# Maven Build Error - Storm-Starter project

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I am getting a build error when I try to build the storm starter project. I don't have any clues on what's going wrong. Any help is appreciated. The error is pasted below,

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ storm-starter ---
Downloading: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/storm/storm-checkstyle/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/storm/storm-checkstyle/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/storm-checkstyle-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.storm:storm-checkstyle:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/storm/storm-checkstyle/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/storm-checkstyle-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.179 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-25T17:42:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project storm-starter: Execution validate of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.storm:storm-checkstyle:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots
```

I could understand that a particular dependency is missing, storm-checkstyle:jar, but couldn't solve it. Please update if trace with debug enabled, is needed.

Comment: `storm-checkstyle` doesn't even exist. https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/storm/

Answer (score 1):

`storm-checkstyle` is here https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/storm-checkstyle. It should be in the directory you cloned Storm to. I'm guessing you forgot to do a full build, so you don't have all the Storm jars locally. Please see https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter#build-and-install-storm-jars-locally.